# Python - Append multiple txt files with partially identical headers/different number of columns

Tags: python

I'm trying to append multiple txt files contained in my working directory (approx. 276 files) using this simple code:

```
files = os.listdir(path='.')

headers = pd.read_csv('first_txt_to_be_read', nrows=0, encoding = 'UTF-16LE', sep = ';').columns.tolist()

df_list = []
for file in files:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding = 'UTF-16LE', usecols = headers))

output = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

However after successfully appending 22 files I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found:
```

The reason is that in the 23rd file the name of some columns is slightly different (i.e. one extra character at the end). Moreover some of the files will also have more columns (i.e. 35 instead of 31). Which is the best approach to tackle this issue? Is there a way to partially match the header?

Using the headers from the most recent file leads to (the most recent file has 35 columns, the oldest 31):

```
ValueError: Passed header names mismatches usecols
```

So even matching partially the header will lead to this error later on when trying to append the most recent file to the oldest.

Comment: run the script without appending the whole file. Only get the column headers and store them in a dataframe, list or dictionary. Then you can first inspect the differences much better and think how to fix them or translate the headers dynamically before appending them to df_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get a list of all possible headers:

```
files = os.listdir(path='.')

header_lst = []
for file in files:
    headers = pd.read_csv('first_txt_to_be_read', nrows=0, encoding = 'UTF-16LE', sep = ';').columns.tolist()
    header_lst.append(headers)
```

Use this to find differences. Then you can either automatically or by hand create a column renaming dictionary like this:

```
col_dict = {"col_1":"col_1",
            "col_1_x":"col_1",
            "col_2":"col_2",
            "col_2_yz":"col_2"
            }
```

Then use the *col_dict* to rename the headers before combining the dataframes together:

```
files = os.listdir(path='.')

df_dict = {}
for file in files:
    headers = pd.read_csv('first_txt_to_be_read', nrows=0, encoding = 'UTF-16LE', sep = ';').columns.tolist()
    df_dict[file] = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding = 'UTF-16LE', usecols = headers).rename(columns=col_dict)

output = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), ignore_index=True)
```