# Appending many excel file using python, but encountering column miss match and NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to append many different excel files with the same columns.

However, some of the files have blank space in them and a few excel file seems to have a mismatch in column content. Therefore, when I tried appending them all at once, the values in my columns all became NaNs. Is there any way I can avoid this problem?

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_csv(file),ignore_index=True)
```

For example:

- All 100 excel files that I have has the same column headers
- But as seen in the image, some of them have miss match in column, others have blanks in the values (highlighted in orange)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg0VR.png)

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342822/python-append-multiple-txt-files-with-partially-identical-headers-different-nu/63343414#63343414 The approach is nearly identical.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for providing the info! This might be a stupid question, Im a newbie coder. The headers for my csv file are actually all correct, but the problem is with content, there is NaN and mismatch within them

Comment: Can you specify the problem? e.g. with examples? It is very unlikely that they have the correct header if you get nan value columns. either the names are not exactly the same, like whitespaces at the end or upper/lower case issues or the column wasn't even present in one of the csv files. Make a example using 1 column which doesn't behave as expected ideally with sample values from the csv file opened via editor etc. Put it into your question but try to keep it short and clear. A good question has code where we can recreate the problem through copy and paste of the code.

Comment: can you open a few of the  the csv with text editor and put the lines in your question 
 where empty space occure or the columns do not match?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for being very helpful! I found out that the problem was that there were whitespace in my of the excel file like you mentioned. If there a good way to remove all the whitespace? ( I will improve on my way of asking question, sadly I  can't put a few lines of the csv cause its sorta confidential

Comment: if you want to know how to remove the whitespaces you might want to create a new question for that or update your question and maybe the tile accordingly. Also I am not interested by the content of the line so you can mask it, but whithout knowing how many commas or delimters there are if there are quotes missing etc. I will not be able to help.